# How do I increase the attachment size limitation and formats in Forums?

Tags: file-uploads, forum

I am working with Forums 3.1.9 on EE 2.5.5 and have run into some limitations that should be modifiable.

1. Attachment file size: I see this note:

> Attachments Max Size: 75KB

How can I increase this?

1. Upload file type. If I try to upload a PDF for a Word document I get the following error:

> The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

I checked /config/mimes.php and both .doc and .pdf files are listed. Do the forums have a difference mimes controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [**EE StackExchange question**](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/189/are-pdfs-still-an-xss-problem-with-ee-uploads) will help you with your mime type issue.

---

You can adjust Forum attachment settings here:

> CP > Modules > Discussion Forum > Forum Management > Default Preferences > Attachment Preferences.