# Having trouble uploading PDFs to a channel

Tags: ee1, file-uploads, xss

This is an EE1 site. Whenever I try to upload a PDF I get an error message saying that there was a problem uploading this file. The permissions on the server are still set to 777 and the XSS filtering is off. I have no idea what else it could be.

Here is the exact error message:

> PDF – There was a problem uploading ‘TEST.pdf’

Comment: We need more details. What is the exact error message? What upload folders have you configured? Exactly which XSS setting have you set (it may be the wrong one). Have you seen this question? http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/q/189/150

Comment: Is it just PDFs, or other files as well? Have you tried PDFs of different sizes? Can you upload via the File Manager? Have you tried uploading into fields which use different directories in other channels?

Comment: Also what are you trying to upload using? Just a regular EE file field? Or are you using assets, or another upload plugin?

Comment: Here is the exact error message: PDF – There was a problem uploading ‘TEST.pdf’. I have tired different size PDFS and files. I'm using just a regular EE field.

Comment: I will have to try the file manager I did not think of that one.

Comment: Can you confirm that the *Allowed File Types* is set to *All Files* (vs. *Images Only*) under the *File Manager* > *File Upload Preferences* screen?

Comment: Yea sure: http://manercpa.com/images/uploads/screen-shot.png

Comment: Hmm, this is a silly question, but is that EE2? or EE1? Are you on the latest build? Something doesn't look quite right. My _Allow File Types_ is a select option, not radio. I thought that changed in EE1 > EE2

Comment: Sadly the client has not upgraded to EE2 yet. That is EE1.

Comment: So, when you tagged this with _ee2_ and said "This is a EE2 site", you meant to say this is an EE1 site. Got it :P Are you on the latest build of EE1? You should be able to do that for free, should be your first step (after taking a backup, of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having searched an old EE 1 site's source it looks as though that's an error triggered by Mark Huot's File fieldtype. Here's the corresponding code snippet from ext.mh_file_ext.php:

```
foreach($file_tmp_names as $file_key=>$file_tmp_name)
{
    if(@move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name, $server_path.$file_names[$file_key]) === FALSE)
    {
        $errors[] = str_replace(array('%{field}', '%{file}'), array($file_field['field_label'], $file_names[$file_key]), $LANG->line('error_transfer'));
    }
}
```

Presumably you have an invalid path configured somewhere or this is a permissions issue. If you remove the `@` before `move_uploaded_file` that will disable error suppression and you should see a PHP error that details exactly why the upload has failed.

Comment: Ok I will try this and get back to you on what the results are.