# Is it possible to disable XSS filtering on Cartthrob?

Tags: cartthrob, config, xss

I'm looking for some hidden configuration settings that will allow me to disable XSS filtering when using Cartthrob. The global EE config item is ignored.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It absolutely is.

You can find information on how to disable XSS filtering on this thread 
[Are PDFs still an XSS problem with EE uploads?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/189/are-pdfs-still-an-xss-problem-with-ee-uploads/193#193)

Comment: Are you sure this works specifically with Cartthrob? After looking through code + docs, it looks like CT sends everything through XSS and ignores any config that is set.

Comment: No I don't know about Cartthrob specifically. The config affects file uploads. Are you talking about the transactional processes going on in an ecommerce site?