# Unable to upload PDF using File Upload

Tags: file-uploads, error, permissions

I have a channel that includes a File field type. I have set two user groups to be able to upload all file types to that field. As a Super Admin I am able to upload there, but members of the other group cannot. I have set the upload directory permissions to 777 and I have confirmed that the group has permissions in EE to upload there - see attached. However, when logged in as a user of the other group, when I try to upload a PDF, I get an error that says:

> The file could not be written to disk.

The file size is far less than the max file site allowed.

Normally I would think this is a directory permissions error. Any help would be appreciated for sorting this out.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With that error when uploading a PDF the first thing to take a look at is *Admin ‣ Security and Privacy ‣ Security and Sessions* and see whether [*"Apply XSS Filtering to Uploaded Files"*](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/security_settings.html#apply-xss-filtering-to-uploaded-files) is set to *"yes."* If it is, try setting it to *"no"* instead.

If that clears it up and you don't want to globally stop applying XSS filtering to uploaded files then there is a [config override](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/system_configuration_overrides.html#xss-clean-member-group-exception) that will let you make only certain member group(s) exempt from the filtering. For example:

```
$config['xss_clean_member_group_exception'] = "6|7";
```

See [this answer](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/193/22) for more.