# What are the implications of Disabling XSS clean?

Tags: solspace-freeform, xss

We're having a few strange problems where by .doc and .pdf files are failing to upload via freeform forms, yet this seems an intermittent issue with tests using the same file. I've noticed this issue can be resolved by disabling XSS clean in the file upload field preferences but would like to know what are the implications of Disabling XSS clean? And if this would create a vulnerability and open our site up to an attack?

Comment: Do the answers in this thread help with your issue? http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/189/are-pdfs-still-an-xss-problem-with-ee-uploads

Comment: Not directly as it's for a recruitment website where we're asking people (non-members) to apply by sending CV's and covering letters as PDF and DOC files. But it's damn handy to know. Thank you!